# Android Studio (2.2.3) error: Default Activity not found with FTC

Tags: javascript, android-studio, robotics

While we were programming we came upon a problem. We have the actual program entirely made. The problem comes when we try to run the program on the phone. This error kept showing up and stopping us from activating the program on the phone: Default Activity not found. We are trying to download it onto a ZTE Phone, and are using Android Studio version 2.2.3.

Comment: Welcome to _StackOverflow_! Here, you can learn [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) properly before you do so. When asking a question, be sure you are [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and always try to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when possible. This way, it's more likely volunteers on SO can help you.